# Crm attribute.contains function returning unexpected value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In plugin when message name is update, I have to save the values of fields which is type of decimal and currency.But when I check whether the field contains a value, unexpectedly contain function returning entity collection, for other attribute returning type of querybyattribute, even if variable is bool it can get different type of value and also if clauses doesn't work. What can cause that?

```
 if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_flighthotelreservationid"))
     {
       IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory)); 
       IOrganizationService orgService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        bool b = entity.Attributes.Contains("new_poscost");//to check what is returning
        bool c = entity.Attributes.Contains("profittl");

        Decimal posTutarı5 = entity.Attributes.Contains("new_poscost") ? ((Money)entity.Attributes["new_poscost"]).Value : 0m;

        Decimal profitTl5 = entity.Attributes.Contains("new_profittl") ? (Decimal)entity.Attributes["new_profittl"] : 0m;

        Decimal totalAmount5 = entity.Attributes.Contains("new_totalamount") ? ((Money)entity.Attributes["new_totalamount"]).Value : 0m;
```

Comment: What is type of `new_flighthotelreservationid` field ? To check for the values in `if(condition)` you have to parse first.

Comment: "new_flighthotelreservationid" is type of lookup.

Comment: in if clause i m checking that does new_flighthotelreservationid attribute of the entity contains a value ,do i need to parse for that.also how i will parse and check in if clause in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what I have understood so far:

`new_flighthotelreservationid` is type `lookup` so:

```
if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_flighthotelreservationid"))   //Check if NULL
{
           //So flight reservation is not NULL
           //Below is to parse lookup
EntityReference Resrv = (EntityReference)entity["new_flighthotelreservationid"];

}

else
{
       //Flight reservation is NULL
}
```

your `if` will only execute if `new_flighthotelreservationid` is not NULL.

you can also `parse and check`:

```
if (((EntityReference)entity["new_flighthotelreservationid"]).Id != null)
{
//Not NULL
}
```

So,there is problem assigning the values to decimal variables:
try like below:

`In case your field is of type decimal`

```
Decimal posTutarı5 = (Decimal)(entity.Attributes.Contains("new_poscost")?entity["new_poscost"] : 0m);
```

`In case your field is of type Currency`

```
Money posTutarı5 = (Money)(entity.Attributes.Contains("new_profittl") ? entity["new_profittl"] : 0m);
```

**Below is another method to get Money value**

```
Money NewProfit=entity["new_profittl"] as Money;
int retailPrice = NewProfit.Value;
```

Comment: in both way if clauses returning true.the problem is that what's wrong with assigning value to decimal variables.i m checking whether  the value exist in attribute. if it's exist, asssign value of attribute if it's not, assign 0. but after theese code lines worked, decimal variables are still null.